# Highlight Cells Using Conditional Formatting Based on Other Cells Value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am having some issues with making some conditional formatting work - I'm trying to Highlight the cells in paris - H&I and J&K based on what is in cell L - If L contains the word "opening" I want J&K highlighted Green and H&I highlighted Red - If L doesn't contain the word "Opening" then I want the reverse - H&I highlighted Green and J&K highlighted Red - I've looked a various forums online and guides but none of them seem to be able to help.

(The cells I want highlighting are blank, so depending on what the outcome of L is - the colour of the cell will then inform the user what cells need to be completed)

Comment: It will be much easier for the volunteer contributors here to help you if you will share a copy of your spreadsheet, with the link permission set to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Answer (score 1):

There are three things to do:

- Add the column ranges separately rather than a single range combining both columns

  - use `J1:J10,K1:K10`
  - don't use `J1:K10`
- Use a custom formula
- Reference Column L as an absolute (`$L1`)

---

**Rules: Columns H and I**

[image: HandI]

---

**Rules: Columns J and K**

[image: JandK]

---

**Example**

[image: Example]